# is it possible to do xml to json transformation in JOLT

Tags: json, xml, mapping, transformation, jolt

Is it possible to do XML to JSON transformation on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception. Like pass XML input and write spec in JSON and get JSON output. If yes, is there any documentation or any example around it?

Comment: Not possble within Jolt, since it is a JSON to JSON transformation library.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for confirming.

Comment: Btw, at what platform do you want to use Jolt, if it's Apache NiFi, the answer of @mattyb might be alternative as a workaround even if using only Jolt is not enough to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was implied in the comments, you'd need to convert the XML to JSON first before using the Jolt app. Although Jolt is a JSON-to-JSON transformation library from the command line, the actual transform is applied to a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) after the JSON has been converted to a POJO.

So in [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/index.html) for example, we were able to leverage that library to convert whatever input you have into a POJO and then apply the Jolt transform to it, take a look at [JoltTransformRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-jolt-record-nar/1.19.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.jolt.record.JoltTransformRecord/index.html) to see how we did that.